# Extract string with in parenthesis if matched (regex)

Tags: php, regex

The string could be as follows.

```
poptype in ('01')
and (a0='169'or a1='169'or a2='169'or a3='169'or a4='169'or a5='169'or a6='169'or a7='169'or a8='169'or a9='169')  
and (sku in ('67798240','67724312','67724313','67460442','67629434'))  
and (geo_code in ('D01365','D01353','D01354','D01356','D01364','D01357','D01555'))
```

The result should be as follows:

**Output required:**

```
(a0='169'or a1='169'or a2='169'or a3='169'or a4='169'or a5='169'or a6='169'or a7='169'or a8='169'or a9='169')
```

If "a0" or "a9" exists in a string, I want to match whole wordings within first parent parenthesis.

Comment: Are you trying to parse some programming language here?

Comment: _"Need a perfect solution"_ - That's when doing a lot of research and making many attempts comes in.

Comment: Boss my problem is too complex, it is just a question plz guide if you think my wordings are not appropriate just edit the question. thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question is off-topic since it's basically "Gimme code" instead of "I'm having issues with my existing code, could you help me?". SO isn't a free coding service and with 2k in rep, you most likely already know this.

Comment: Anyways, I just tried to explain my question in detail.

Comment: I would recommend that you rewrite your question to include your attempts, proper example in data, expected out data and with an explanation where, in your existing code, you're stuck.

Comment: _“Anyways, I just tried to explain my question in detail”_ - a slightly better phrased wish list, is still just a wish list. We don’t do wish lists here, we ain’t Santa’s Elves. _You_ need to show us at least something that you tried, show us _some_ effort you made already.

Comment: If you don't put efforts on solving your own problem, then why do others have to?

Comment: https://regexr.com/4a1pu

Comment: I tried as above but I am not sure how can I select whole string within parenthesis.

Comment: Give `(\([^\(]+(a0|a9)[^\)]+\))` a go. (Might need some refining, but as a starting point it should do.)

Comment: Thanks, @04FS :-)

Comment: @04FS Please post your answer so I can mark it as "accept"

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
\(.*(?:a0|a9).*\)
```

Check out at: https://regex101.com/r/SWtZh4/1
Basically it matches everything within the brackets if a0 or a9 have been found in it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if there no "Enter" in the text this regex not working.

Comment: I adjusted the regex to include line breks and new lines into account: https://regex101.com/r/SWtZh4/2

Answer (score 0):

> If "a0" or "a9" exists in a string, I want to match whole wordings within first parent parenthesis.

`(\([^\(]+(a0|a9)[^\)]+\))`

That should basically do what you want.

Looking for a opening brace, followed by any number of non-opening-brace characters, then a0 or a9, and then "mirrored" for the closing brace on the other end.